# PySide2 and Qt Designer: unable to make QGroupBox expand in runtime

Tags: qt, runtime, pyside2, autoresize, qgroupbox

I'm a Tkinter user, but I decided to use Qt library, 'cause the final result is more pro. I'm re-coding an old interface, that is populated in runtime based on the contents of an ini file.

IMG starting point:

[image: IMG starting point]

But when I do it, the news widgets almost stack ones over the others. If I expand the window manually, the widgets use all the vertical space, but I tried to make them to stay in the top of window.

IMG populated:

[image: IMG populated],

IMG manually resized (only vert allowed):

[image: IMG manually resized (only vert allowed)]

That's the Qt Designer UI:

[image: IMG Qt Designer UI]

That's the complete code generated by QTD:

```
################################################################################
# Form generated from reading UI file 'limpia_Hot_Folders 6uSOTvD.ui'
#
# Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QRect, QSize, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import QFont
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.actionActualizar = None
        self.actionEditar_Fiery_y_HF = None
        self.actionSalir = None
        self.actionSeleccionar_todo = None
        self.actionInvertir_seleccion = None
        self.actionSeleccionar_nada = None
        self.actionAyuda = None
        self.actionAcerca_de = None
        self.actionPapelera = None
        self.actionPermanente = None
        self.WDT_central = None
        self.gridLayout = None
        self.BTN_vaciar = None
        self.GRB_fierys = None
        self.grid_GRB_fierys = None
        self.RBT_fiery_1 = None
        self.CHB_fiery_1 = None
        self.gridLayout = None
        self.VLS_top = None
        self.VLS_mid = None
        self.HZS_izq = None
        self.HZS_der = None
        self.LBL_flecha = None
        self.GRB_hotfolders = None
        self.vert_lay_GRB_hotfolders = None
        self.CHB_hotfolder_1 = None
        self.VLS_down = None
        self.Menubar = None
        self.menuArchivo = None
        self.menuSeleccion = None
        self.menuAyuda = None
        self.menuModo_Borrado = None

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(420, 170)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed,
                                 QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(420, 170))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(420, 2000))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Limpia Hot Folders")

        self.actionActualizar = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionActualizar.setObjectName("actionActualizar")
        self.actionActualizar.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(True)

        self.actionEditar_Fiery_y_HF = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionEditar_Fiery_y_HF.setObjectName("actionEditar_Fiery_y_HF")

        self.actionSalir = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSalir.setObjectName("actionSalir")

        self.actionSeleccionar_todo = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSeleccionar_todo.setObjectName("actionSeleccionar_todo")

        self.actionInvertir_seleccion = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionInvertir_seleccion.setObjectName("actionInvertir_seleccion")

        self.actionSeleccionar_nada = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSeleccionar_nada.setObjectName("actionSeleccionar_nada")

        self.actionAyuda = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAyuda.setObjectName("actionAyuda")

        self.actionAcerca_de = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAcerca_de.setObjectName(u"actionAcerca_de")

        self.actionPapelera = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPapelera.setObjectName("actionPapelera")
        self.actionPapelera.setCheckable(True)

        self.actionPermanente = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPermanente.setObjectName("actionPermanente")
        self.actionPermanente.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionPermanente.setChecked(False)

        self.WDT_central = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.WDT_central.setObjectName("WDT_central")
        self.WDT_central.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                 QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.WDT_central.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.WDT_central.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.WDT_central.setMaximumSize(QSize(2000, 2000))

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.WDT_central)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.BTN_vaciar = QPushButton(self.WDT_central)
        self.BTN_vaciar.setObjectName("BTN_vaciar")
        sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum,
                                  QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.BTN_vaciar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.BTN_vaciar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.BTN_vaciar.setFont(font)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.BTN_vaciar,
                                  4,
                                  1,
                                  1,
                                  3)

        self.GRB_fierys = QGroupBox(self.WDT_central)
        self.GRB_fierys.setObjectName("GRB_fierys")
        sizePolicy2 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                  QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy2.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy2.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.GRB_fierys.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.GRB_fierys.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.GRB_fierys.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0))
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setPointSize(9)
        self.GRB_fierys.setFont(font1)
        self.GRB_fierys.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.grid_GRB_fierys = QGridLayout(self.GRB_fierys)
        self.grid_GRB_fierys.setObjectName("grid_GRB_fierys")
        self.grid_GRB_fierys.setContentsMargins(20, -1, -1, -1)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.GRB_fierys,
                                  1,
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  1)

        # Espaciador vertical
        self.VLS_top = QSpacerItem(10,
                                   10,
                                   QSizePolicy.Minimum,
                                   QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.VLS_top,
                                0,
                                1,
                                1,
                                3)

        self.VLS_mid = QSpacerItem(20,
                                   10,
                                   QSizePolicy.Minimum,
                                   QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.VLS_mid,
                                3,
                                1,
                                1,
                                3)

        # Espaciador horizontal
        self.HZS_izq = QSpacerItem(10,
                                   20,
                                   QSizePolicy.Fixed,
                                   QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.HZS_izq,
                                1,
                                0,
                                2,
                                1)

        self.HZS_der = QSpacerItem(10,
                                   20,
                                   QSizePolicy.Fixed,
                                   QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.HZS_der,
                                1,
                                4,
                                2,
                                1)

        self.LBL_flecha = QLabel(self.WDT_central)
        self.LBL_flecha.setObjectName("LBL_flecha")
        sizePolicy4 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed,
                                  QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy4.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy4.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy4.setHeightForWidth(self.LBL_flecha.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.LBL_flecha.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy4)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.LBL_flecha,
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  2,
                                  1)

        self.GRB_hotfolders = QGroupBox(self.WDT_central)
        self.GRB_hotfolders.setObjectName("GRB_hotfolders")
        sizePolicy5 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                  QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy5.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy5.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy5.setHeightForWidth(self.GRB_hotfolders.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.GRB_hotfolders.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy5)
        self.GRB_hotfolders.setFont(font1)
        self.GRB_hotfolders.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.vert_lay_GRB_hotfolders = QVBoxLayout(self.GRB_hotfolders)
        self.vert_lay_GRB_hotfolders.setObjectName("vert_lay_GRB_hotfolders")
        self.vert_lay_GRB_hotfolders.setContentsMargins(20, -1, -1, -1)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.GRB_hotfolders,
                                  1,
                                  3,
                                  2,
                                  1)

        self.VLS_down = QSpacerItem(10,
                                    10,
                                    QSizePolicy.Minimum,
                                    QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.VLS_down,
                                5,
                                1,
                                1,
                                3)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.WDT_central)

        self.Menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.Menubar.setObjectName("Menubar")
        self.Menubar.setEnabled(True)
        self.Menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 420, 21))
        font3 = QFont()
        font3.setItalic(False)
        self.Menubar.setFont(font3)
        self.Menubar.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
        self.Menubar.setDefaultUp(False)

        self.menuArchivo = QMenu(self.Menubar)
        self.menuArchivo.setObjectName("menuArchivo")

        self.menuSeleccion = QMenu(self.Menubar)
        self.menuSeleccion.setObjectName("menuSeleccion")

        self.menuAyuda = QMenu(self.Menubar)
        self.menuAyuda.setObjectName("menuAyuda")

        self.menuModo_Borrado = QMenu(self.Menubar)
        self.menuModo_Borrado.setObjectName("menuModo_Borrado")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.Menubar)

        self.Menubar.addAction(self.menuArchivo.menuAction())
        self.Menubar.addAction(self.menuSeleccion.menuAction())
        self.Menubar.addAction(self.menuModo_Borrado.menuAction())
        self.Menubar.addAction(self.menuAyuda.menuAction())

        self.menuArchivo.addAction(self.actionActualizar)
        self.menuArchivo.addAction(self.actionEditar_Fiery_y_HF)
        self.menuArchivo.addSeparator()
        self.menuArchivo.addAction(self.actionSalir)

        self.menuSeleccion.addAction(self.actionSeleccionar_todo)
        self.menuSeleccion.addAction(self.actionInvertir_seleccion)
        self.menuSeleccion.addAction(self.actionSeleccionar_nada)

        self.menuAyuda.addAction(self.actionAyuda)
        self.menuAyuda.addAction(self.actionAcerca_de)

        self.menuModo_Borrado.addAction(self.actionPermanente)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.actionActualizar.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                 "A&ctualizar",
                                                                 None))
        self.actionActualizar.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                     "Ctrl+A",
                                                                     None))
        self.actionEditar_Fiery_y_HF.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                        "&Editar Fiery y HF",
                                                                        None))
        self.actionEditar_Fiery_y_HF.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                            "Ctrl+E",
                                                                            None))
        self.actionSalir.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                            "&Salir",
                                                            None))
        self.actionSalir.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                "Ctrl+X",
                                                                None))
        self.actionSeleccionar_todo.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                       "Seleccionar &todo",
                                                                       None))
        self.actionSeleccionar_todo.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                           "Ctrl+T",
                                                                           None))
        self.actionInvertir_seleccion.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                         "&Invertir selección",
                                                                         None))
        self.actionInvertir_seleccion.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                             "Ctrl+I",
                                                                             None))
        self.actionSeleccionar_nada.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                       "Seleccionar &nada",
                                                                       None))
        self.actionSeleccionar_nada.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                           "Ctrl+N",
                                                                           None))
        self.actionAyuda.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                            "&Ayuda",
                                                            None))
        self.actionAyuda.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                "Alt+Y",
                                                                None))
        self.actionAcerca_de.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                "Acerca &de...",
                                                                None))
        self.actionPapelera.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                               "Papelera",
                                                               None))
        self.actionPermanente.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                 "&Permanente",
                                                                 None))
        self.BTN_vaciar.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                           "VACIAR HOTFOLDERS (Papelera)",
                                                           None))
        self.BTN_vaciar.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                               "Return",
                                                               None))
        self.GRB_fierys.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                            "Fiery",
                                                            None))                                                   
        self.LBL_flecha.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                           ">>",
                                                           None))
        self.GRB_hotfolders.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                "Hot folders",
                                                                None))
        self.menuArchivo.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                             "&Archivo",
                                                             None))
        self.menuSeleccion.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                               "&Selección",
                                                               None))
        self.menuAyuda.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                           "A&yuda",
                                                           None))
        self.menuModo_Borrado.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                                  "Modo &Borrado",
                                                                  None))
    # retranslateUi
```

And that's the class that do population (manual method, not automated yet):

```
from os import path
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from ui_limpia_Hot_Folders import Ui_MainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QRect, QSize, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import QFont
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QCheckBox, QRadioButton, QSizePolicy


class Interfaz(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """Ayuda gráfica para limpiar las hotfolders de Fiery.
    Selecciona automáticamente las que tienen trabajos en su listado."""

    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.root = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.root.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Fierys & Hot Folders Editor v2.0')

        # Mostramos la ventana
        self.show()

        # Esta variable controla la existencia de la ventana de fieryeditorQT
        self._app = None

        self.version = 'V 2.0'
        self.fecha_version = 'marzo de 2024'
        self.tipo_borrado = 'a la papelera'

        self.root.actionActualizar.triggered.connect(self.__listar_maquinas)
        self.root.BTN_vaciar.clicked.connect(self.__listar_maquinas)

    def __listar_maquinas(self):
        sizePolicy3 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed,
                                  QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy3.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy3.setVerticalStretch(0)

        # Añadimos un nuevo fiery, primero su checkbox
        self.root.CHB_fiery_2 = QCheckBox(self.root.GRB_fierys)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_2.setObjectName("CHB_fiery_2")
        font2 = QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(8)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_2.setFont(font2)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_2.setTristate(True)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_2.setText("Fiery_2 : 12")
        self.root.CHB_fiery_2.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.root.grid_GRB_fierys.addWidget(self.root.CHB_fiery_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        # Y ahora el radiobutton
        self.root.RBT_fiery_2 = QRadioButton(self.root.GRB_fierys)
        self.root.RBT_fiery_2.setObjectName("RBT_fiery_2")
        self.root.RBT_fiery_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy3)
        self.root.RBT_fiery_2.setStatusTip("")
        self.root.RBT_fiery_2.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.root.grid_GRB_fierys.addWidget(self.root.RBT_fiery_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        # Añadimos un nuevo fiery, primero su checkbox
        self.root.CHB_fiery_3 = QCheckBox(self.root.GRB_fierys)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_3.setObjectName("CHB_fiery_3")
        font2 = QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(8)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_3.setFont(font2)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_3.setTristate(True)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_3.setText("Fiery_3 : 15")
        self.root.CHB_fiery_3.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.root.grid_GRB_fierys.addWidget(self.root.CHB_fiery_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        # Y ahora el radiobutton
        self.root.RBT_fiery_3 = QRadioButton(self.root.GRB_fierys)
        self.root.RBT_fiery_3.setObjectName("RBT_fiery_3")
        self.root.RBT_fiery_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy3)
        self.root.RBT_fiery_3.setStatusTip("")
        self.root.RBT_fiery_3.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.root.grid_GRB_fierys.addWidget(self.root.RBT_fiery_3, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        # Añadimos un nuevo fiery, primero su checkbox
        self.root.CHB_fiery_4 = QCheckBox(self.root.GRB_fierys)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_4.setObjectName("CHB_fiery_4")
        font2 = QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(8)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_4.setFont(font2)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_4.setTristate(True)
        self.root.CHB_fiery_4.setText("Fiery_4 : 8")
        self.root.CHB_fiery_4.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.root.grid_GRB_fierys.addWidget(self.root.CHB_fiery_4, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        # Y ahora el radiobutton
        self.root.RBT_fiery_4 = QRadioButton(self.root.GRB_fierys)
        self.root.RBT_fiery_4.setObjectName("RBT_fiery_4")
        self.root.RBT_fiery_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy3)
        self.root.RBT_fiery_4.setStatusTip("")
        self.root.RBT_fiery_4.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.root.grid_GRB_fierys.addWidget(self.root.RBT_fiery_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        # Añadimos una hotfolder
        self.root.CHB_hotfolder_1 = QCheckBox(self.root.GRB_hotfolders)
        self.root.CHB_hotfolder_1.setObjectName("CHB_hotfolder_1")
        self.root.CHB_hotfolder_1.setFont(font2)
        self.root.vert_lay_GRB_hotfolders.addWidget(self.root.CHB_hotfolder_1)
        self.root.CHB_hotfolder_1.setText("Hotfolder 1  :  12")

        self.root.GRB_fierys.adjustSize()
        self.root.GRB_hotfolders.adjustSize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    window = Interfaz()
    app.exec_()
```

I use abbrevs in the name of the widgets to easilly identify and search them in Pycharm structure:
WDT - widget, BTN - button., LBL - label, GRB - groupbox, VLS - vertical spacer, HZS - horizontal spacer.

I have tried a lot of solutions, but almost all are about use Qt Designer auto layouts, and I'm doing from scratch.

Comment: Have you tried to call `QWidget::adjustSize()`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]: the pyuic generated file (or, better, the UI file from Designer) and the simplest/shortest code example that we could easily copy/paste/run in order to allow us to *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: @Atmo, eeeeeh, nope... What you see is what I tried. Again, remember I'm using Python, not C++.

Comment: @musicamante, I can upload the three files, ui from QTD, python code of that ui and the class that calls this ui. Give me a minute...

Comment: @Viper_7691 1. on Atmo's suggestion: that's irrelevant, function names are almost always identical in Python (except for its reserved keywords), so it would just be something like `self.adjustSize()`; 2. about providing a MRE, ensure that you properly follow what suggested in the link above (we don't need the full code!); 3. it seems like you've been trying to edit/merge code generated by the pyuic utility into your program, which discouraged (as the warning on top of those files suggest), please see how [to use Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) in PyQt.

Comment: Well @musicamante, I don't know how to upload files...

Comment: @Viper_7691 You need to [edit] your post. Ensure that you read how to correctly [format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and remember to properly check that the syntax is valid in the post preview before submitting.

Comment: @musicamante, 1) AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout' object has no attribute 'adjustSize'   2) I can't upload the files, but the code I provided is the relevant part for this case, at last.   3) the code that you think is edited in the QTD generated code isn't, it's the part of customization in the calling class.   4) I don't see what is wrong with the format of the code.

Comment: @Viper_7691 1. `adjustSize()` is a QWidget member, that error is because you're calling that function against a layout; 2. nobody doubts that the code is relevant, but it's insufficient to allow us to *properly understand* what/where actually the problem is; 3. I wrote "it seems" (your second snippet clearly shows elements taken from it): one essential step of providing a MRE is to get rid of anything not required to reproduce the issue (so you should attempt their removal especially if you don't know what it does); 4. I never said that your format is wrong, but to *ensure* that it's correct.

Comment: I tried adjustSize() on QGroupBox first, then on layouts, then in MainWindow. It does NOTHING or it rise the error.

Comment: Do not comment what you tried, edit your question to show it in the code instead. Anyway, your screenshot labeled *IMG manually resized* shows it just works when you resize your window manually, so this is what you must to programatically too. @musicamante said to call `self.adjustSize()` for that reason: without resizing the window itself, there will be no free space for the group box to expand into. I tried on my computer, connecting adjustSize to the click of a button (after the radio is added) and it works.

Comment: As you have not edited the code in your question, I can only guess that you do not call `adjustSize()` on the main window after adding the radio button or it could be disturbed by the spacers you have put around your controls (that is not a good use of spacers, the same layout can be obtained with only size policies and align options from `QLayout` -> you should remove them all). In the off chance you do it correctly but it still does not work, please read https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#activate including the methods from the *See also* section and try to use them in your code too.

Comment: @Viper_7691 Trying things randomly rarely provides valid and reliable results. If you want our help, we need a proper MRE. Without it, *nobody* will be able to give you any answer at all.

Comment: @Atmo, ty, but I didn't do anything more yesterday, cause I was asleep. ;-) Anyway, I tried adjustSize() after the last widget was added to groupbox. I tried with the group itself, his layout (not allowed, of course) and the central widget, with no result at all. I ll edit the code to show ALL code.

Comment: There have you the COMPLETE codes (less the methods, they are the old tkinter ones and I must rewrite them). Not the real behavour,  when you press the VACIAR button the QGroupBox is populated programatically. In the real one (not implemented yet) the script reads a config.ini file and populate Fiery and Hotfolders with the info found in there. That's only a way to test the interface before code the rest (no point to code it if the UI doesn't do what I want).

Comment: And before you ask it, the UI part commented are the definition of the checkboxes and radiobuttons, I have not deleted yet, I'll do when the ui is final.

Comment: @Atmo, I'll check about spacers.

Comment: @Viper_7691 Please do as told. We never asked for the *complete* code. Please remove anything that is not related to the issue, such as those empty methods and their connections, which are not relevant for the question. We should be able to focus only on the problem, anything else is just noise that makes your code distracting.

Comment: @musicamante, there you have it. I don't understand the problem of some passing methods, but, hey, no prob, you have it removed yet.

Comment: @Atmo, I have tried activate() and update() with the groupbox and updateGeometry() with the layouts. No one did the job.

Comment: @Viper_7691 I've explained it: we need to be able to focus only on the code that allows us to reproduce the issue, anything else doesn't add anything useful to the question and only distract us from properly focusing on your actual issue. That said, try resetting the minimum size property of the main window (be careful: you should not set it to 0, but actually *reset* it by clicking the small red arrow). Setting a minimum dimension does not only ensure that the widget has a minimum size, but also tells its layout that the contents may be *stretched* in order to allow that minimum size.

Comment: @Viper_7691: It is supposed to be the opposite. Anyway, I have a C++ MRE (about 25-30 lines which is what your code should also be) on my computer and can confirm `adjustSize()` is enough for the window to resize. I am, as you guessed, a C++ developer so I could eventually demonstrate it with your Qt designer file (it is just an XML) but not with what you provided (The Python output of uic).

Answer (score 0):

I post it like answer, to help someone else with the same problem. Easier to find than buried between 20 comments.
@musicamante have the solution:

> Try resetting the minimum size property of the main window (be careful: you should not set it to 0, but actually reset it by clicking the small red arrow). Setting a minimum dimension does not only ensure that the widget has a minimum size, but also tells its layout that the contents may be stretched in order to allow that minimum size.

Thanks!

if @musicamante publish the answer, I'll delete this message and vote it like OK.